# $_GET navigation without the use of ?page=

Tags: php, html

**Solved!**

first of all, I know I can use "?page=..." but I do not like that variable in my URL. Now after some searching I found a site which uses the $_GET['page'] without showing the "?page=" in the url.

But I'm having a bit of a struggle with the code. I cannot seem to get this code to work. I know it works on an other site, but not on my site. I cannot seem to find how it works on the other site.

**this is the menu code:**

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="even_voorstellen">Even voorstellen</a></li>
<li><a href="de_kennismaking">De kennismaking</a></li>
```

**and this is the php code:**

```
$sExpressie = "(http:|ftp:|shttp:|www.|.php|.pl|.cgi|.asp|index.php)";  

if(isset($_GET['pagina']) && eregi($sExpressie,$_GET['pagina']))
{
   include("pages/home.php");
}
else 
{
   if(isset($_GET['pagina']) && file_exists('Pages/' . $_GET['pagina'] . ".php")) 
   {                                
     include('pages/' . $_GET['pagina'] . ".php");
   }                    
   else 
   { 
     include("pages/home.php");
   } 
}
```

I don't understand how this code works. In my website the "$GET['pagina']" is never filled, which is logical. But how can it be filled in the other website?

Thanks a lot everyone! 
Solution:

**Add the following to your .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Read on  `.htaccess`

Comment: As @AbraCadaver says, .htaccess is what you want, but while you're at it: [read the PHP docs](http://php.net/eregi). `ereg` and `eregi` are _deprecated_ (and have been for years), use `preg_*` instead

Comment: Wordpress works like this, you might look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pages/$1.php [NC,L]
```

For example, if you now navigate to http://yourwebsite.com/fubar, your website will load the page located at pages/fubar.php without changing the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RewriteRule` within your .htaccess file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [L, QSA] #(.*) is lazy and you may want to just catch [a-z0-9].
```

This will "rewrite" a request like http://example.com/?pagina=even_voorstellen into something like http://example.com/even_voorstellen. Your `index.php` can then use `$_GET['pagina']` to call the respective page.

[image]

Comment: So, 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$       index.php?pagina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$   index.php?pagina=$2&id=$1 [L]

is what I am looking for as i understand i right? :)

Comment: Yes, but im unsure what `id` is for in the URL. You'll want to remove `[L]` in your first rule as that means `END` and it'll stop rewriting.